# Half sized block

Tags: piece-information, size

I know a standard block is 9.6mm tall and a plate is 1/3 of that at 3.2mm.  I found several blocks that are 4.8mm tall or 1/2.  What are they called?  Are they still made and where can I get some?

Comment: Do you have any pictures of those?

Comment: Are they really LEGO bricks? (Can you see the LEGO marking on them, are they compatible with known LEGO bricks?)

Comment: I know there are some LEGO Technic parts that are half a stud tall, but they are not bricks. Is this what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be describing *LEGO Modulex* bricks.

[image]

[image]

Video of the history of *LEGO Modulex* ***[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8KxYKSBzhI)***.

And a post on *LEGO* brick sizes ***[HERE](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6995/middle-size-lego-bricks)***.